# Why is this piece of code in Go O(n²) and not O(n)?

Tags: go, time-complexity

I'm in the middle of reading [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html), and there is a piece of code which I think is `O(n)` complexity yet it is `O(n²)`. Why is this `for range` loop considered to be `O(n²)`?

It is found [here (under #interfaces)](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces)

```golang
type Sequence []int
...
func (s Sequence) String() string {
    ...
    for i, elem := range s { // Loop is O(N²); will fix that in next example.
        if i > 0 {
            str += " "
        }
        str += fmt.Sprint(elem)
    }
    ...
}
```

The reason I think it is `O(n)` is because there is only one iteration over `s`, and the `if` statement and `fmt.Sprint` should not be in `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: I's not the `Sequence` traversal, which is `O(n)`, but building the `str` piecemeal: on each `+=` the `str` is copied anew with sufficient allocation of the free space at the end of the new memory block, and then the result of `fmt.Sprintf(elem)` is appended. That is `O(n²)` in terms of memory.

Comment: In a reasonably up-to-date Go, use [`strings.Builder`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder) to carry out tasks like this.

Comment: Thank you for answering and for suggesting a better replacement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Every time you concatenate `str += fmt.Sprint(elem)` you create a new `String` that has to transfer (copy) the characters of the prev `str` into the new one. In step 1 you copy 1 char, in step 2, 2, etc. This gives `n(n+1)/2` copies. Hence the complexity is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thank you, that answers it! Will mark this answer as correct shortly.